# How to add leading zeros to a batch of file names before a key character using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to add leading zeros to a batch of file names before an underscore.

e.g.: going from 123_ABC.pdf to 000123_ABC.pdf

The goal is that before the underscore there should be 6 numbers, and I therefore need to add leading zeros.

I have done this before for cases where i needed to add leading zeros to a file name that was pure numbers, which is the below code, but I'm not sure how to adapt it to the scenario above.

```
Get-ChildItem "[Folder Location]" | ForEach-Object {
    $NewName = "{0:d6}$($_.Extension)" -f [int]$_.BaseName
    Rename-Item $_.FullName $NewName
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If there are no leading digits, should 6 0's be added? Or no matter what new name will always be `000oldname`?

Comment: if the file name was e.g.: _ABC.pdf, i would want to change it to 000000_ABC.pdf . If no underscore then no action

Comment: as further clarification, it should ideally also only look at the first underscore if there is more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can get the new file name according to your specifications:

```
$input = "123_ABC.pdf","_ABC.pdf", "qksdcfg.pdf", "0140ABC.pdf", "014_0_ABC.pdf"

foreach($filename in $input) {

    # split on first underscore
    $parts = $filename -split "_",2

    # if there are more than 1 parts (= there is an underscore in the filename)
    if($parts.Count -gt 1) {

        # add leading 0's and join with the file name remainder
        "{0:d6}_{1}" -f [int]$parts[0], $parts[1]
    } else {
        $filename
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
000123_ABC.pdf
000000_ABC.pdf
qksdcfg.pdf
0140ABC.pdf
000014_0_ABC.pdf
```

Mixed with your code:

```
Get-ChildItem "[Folder Location]" | ForEach-Object {
    $parts = $_.Name -split "_",2
    if($parts.Count -gt 1) {
        $NewName = "{0:d6}_{1}" -f [int]$parts[0], $parts[1]
    } else {
        $NewName = $_.Name
    }
    Rename-Item $_.FullName $NewName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\*.pdf" -file -filter "*_*" | %{ 
    $Array=$_.Name.Split('_')
    $NewName="{0:d6}_{1}" -f [int]$Array[0], ($Array[1..($Array.Length -1)] -join '_')
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $NewName  
}
```